# Presenting Modally from SplitViewController Creates Unintentional Nav Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I present a ViewController from a segue on a DetailViewController. The user taps a button, and the intended ViewController "slides up" via a modal. When I call self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil), however, the ViewController "slides down" as expected but a new Navigation Controller has been created.

How can I dismiss my modal and have only the original Detail ViewController present? I've tried self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil), and popping all of the ViewControllers, however it seems like the Navigation Controller only gets created when the dismiss has been called so I cannot directly reference it. Thanks!

My Storyboard:

[image]

When the VC is presented via modal:

[image]

After it has been dismissed:

[image]

Comment: My suggestion would be to present from the split view controller, not from the detail view controller.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the input; I tried your suggestion and it still creates the Navigation Controller however.

Comment: @moosgrn Having the same issue. My current work around (which might not apply for you) is to force the presentation to be in portrait mode, but this only works because the presented view is an informative PDF and my app supports portrait mode. Would love to see a solution to this

Comment: @Leftasanexercise thanks for the input; sorry your having the same issue but glad you found a workaround. Unfortunately my presented content is ~16:9 so I have to use landscape. Since I posted this I've tried to segue from the SplitVC, the MasterVC, the DetailVC, as well instantiating it and/or putting it in other nav controllers. Still working on it!